# How to give a combinatorial proof for: If $n$ and $k$ are positive integers with $n=2k$ then $\frac{n!}{2^k}$ is an integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinatorial-proofs

How can i give a combinatorial proof for if $n$ and $k$ are positive integers with $n=2k$ then $\dfrac{n!}{2^k}$ is an integer?

Comment: *Hint:* among the multiplicands of $n!$, how many of them are even?

Comment: In how many ways can you put the members of  $k$ couples in a row if the members of a couple are considered interchangeable?  (Thus the arrangements $X_1Y_2X_2Y_1$ and $X_2Y_2X_1Y_1$ are considered equivalent).

Comment: Hint: $6!/8=(6/2)(5)(4/2)(3)(2/2)$.

Comment: Better write $\frac{(2k)!}{2^k}$, $n$ is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $k$ pairs where the objects in a given pair are identical but the objects in any two pairs are distinct. That is to say, you have two of object $a$, two of object $b$, and so on down to two of object $k$.

Thus you have $n=2k$ objects all told and every object has a unique duplicate.

Now the number of ways to arrange those $n$ objects in a line is precisely your quotient, which is therefore an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The permutations of the socks from $k$ pairs can be obtained as all permutations with the socks of every pairs considered identical, and all these permutations can be duplicated by swapping the socks of the pairs.

E.g.

$ABBA$ yields the four $ABba,aBbA,ABba,abBA$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=2k$, $\dfrac{n!}{2^k}$ can be written as the multinomial $\dbinom{n}{2,\dots,2}$ (with $k$ $2$'s), and is therefore an integer.